# CS:GO Online Players vs Expert Bots

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

As the title says, I have heard at many places that the expert bots are very easy. But I find them **too difficult**. They have *very fast reaction time* and *very good accuracy*. I want to know whether the top online players or world top gamers are better than expert bots?

Just curios to know.

Although **getting at 1st place with expert bots isn't hard**, but *beating their reaction times and accuracy* is tough.

Comment: First question that you have to honestly answer first: are you good at FPS? There are many things that normal people feel difficult, compared to pro players who have mastered most techniques in very detailed way.

Comment: @antimo I'm good at FPS, but not pro. I lack techniques like hiding behind the cover and then firing. I always stand in front of enemies and shoot. My accuracy is good. More than 60% of my kills are due to headshots. But I want to know whether the best players of CS GO can handle expert bots?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to be pro to be better than bots. Most average players and probably many below average players are better than bots. Do consider that bots have a skill level too if you're playing offline with bots.

Bots do behave unpredictably at times though. Sometimes you can be within a few feet of a bot and they won't react, and at other times it seems they hear you coming and pre-fire you like a pro would.

Whether playing with bots or regular players, try to remember that you should always try to play close to cover when it's available, so you can fallback to a safe position if required. Don't stand still in open spaces for a long period, as even bots can kill you if you're not moving. Most players usually `ADADAD` between taking shots to make themselves harder to hit. Use shift when walking if you feel that you are potentially close to opponents, I do feel if bots hear you coming they react quicker, which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes bots outsmart players on expert
But most of the times player can ez them

if you are playing casual most of the chance are expert bots getting beaten up

here comes the difference
players have bad spray while bots aim before shooting
although player aim can be a bit bad due to their skill or bad mouse senstivity
while bots have something called "AIMBOT" which has a high accuracy
bots cant outsmart player but ai works a bit different
AI works like

1. They learn from mistakes
2. they are always devloping
3. in a match if they survive longer they gain more chance to kill you

although through my experience
Players can be killed easily than bots